# Manipulate my loop for javascript stop and start position

Tags: javascript, loops

I have an assignment where I need to manipulate my loop the song bottles of beer. How would I manipulate it stop at clears it all out. and restart at lines of code in the file.

I'm a beginner so please be gentle.

```
var i = 99;
while (true)
{
    console.log(i + "  lines of code in the file" + " " + i +  " lines of code" + " " + "John strikes one out, clears it all out" + " " + i + " " + "lines of code in the file");
    i -= 1;
    if (i == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue, it seems to be correct to me? Check regarding template strings once.

Comment: I want it to say 99  lines of code in the file 99 lines of code John strikes one out, clears it all out 98 lines of code in the file

Comment: I updated the comment please check .

Comment: Thank you so much :) I really appreciate it!

Comment: If you are ok with the solution , could you please accept it ?

Comment: yes! sorry. Im still new.

Comment: Okay , I can explain , when you find the answer is upto the mark and clarifies what you wanted, you can accept it and upvote it . This also helps others who face the same issue. Happy Learning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change console.log to this :

```
var i = 99;
while (true)
{
    console.log(`${i} lines of code in the file  ${i} lines of code John strikes one out, clears it all out.
 ${i-1} lines of code in the file`);
    i -= 1;
    if (i == 1)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```